# Updating Android make it to user more data transfer, now there is no way to block data by default

Tags: updates, mobile-data, android-10

I have accidentally updated my Android One phone to v10 of 2020-05-01 and now each time I switch-on the phone data transfer is also on.

How can I disable data transfer by default so I need to manually enable it whenever I want.

Previously once I switched-off the data, by sliding a drawer from top of the screen and tapping data transfer triangle, it was off until I really made it on. It also stayed up when I rebooted the system.

Comment: How to you enable/disable mobile data? Have you also disabled VoiceOverLTE (VoLTE) because if VoLTE is enabled your device may still open a data connection even if you disabled it. This is required as LTE has only data, hence voice calls have to be done via data, or otherwise your phone has to go down to 3G/2G for voice calls.

Comment: Operators around here make a distinction between voice calls and data connections. Honestly I never came across VoLTE term, but even if is in use it is not charged against may data quota. Only "true" data transfer lowers the remaining limit. Not sure though how the operator differentiates the two.

Comment: Theoretically you are correct VoLTE data calls are not charged, however 99% of all mobile network operators don't manage to correctly distinguish between VoLTE traffic and regular traffic. This always makes problems when you are abroad and you want to disable mobile data because of high roaming costs. Looks like the customers should complain more often about wrong charged data connections. If the complaint handling costs more and more money they finally start implementing data charging correctly.

Comment: I am almost sure that VoLTE is charged correctly against voice limit as the problem appeared recently just after updating Android. Before not even a byte was charged as long as I did not enable the transfer on the sliding drawer. Now after each reboot sometimes even a megabyte gets charged which outside of EU starts a new costly package and even within EU makes me start counting the period when extra charges take place. This is hell annoying enough to consider to switch to another OS.

Comment: It is not the complete call data that is charged incorrectly, typically some signalling data and other smaller data are charged wrong. It may by only up to a few hundred KB per day but depending on your data plan (especially on roaming) this still can cost you some money.

Comment: In this case how would you explain that just a week ago data transfer stayed off and now gets on each time I restart the phone?

Comment: I would assume that the old version did not had VoLTE support or the new version simply has a bug may be introduced by the device manufacturer modifications.